In linux, can kernel thread be preempted when the kernel be configured with PREEMTP_NONE?
I have a kernel be configured as PREEMPT_NONE, and I have a kernel thread to do some I/O task, and have a user space app also do some I/O task. They work correct seperately, but when I have them run at the same time, the user space app become very laggy. Before, I always thought the kernel thread is same as user thread when scheduled. But now I wonder if the kernel thread can be preempted with PREEMPT_NONE or not. Ant I also want to know when do the preempt happen in both user thread and kernel thread cases.
Before, I always thought the kernel thread is same as user thread when scheduled. But now I wonder if the kernel thread can be preempted with PREEMPT_NONE or not. Ant I also want to know when do the preempt happen in both user thread and kernel thread cases.

PREEMPT_NONE does not distinguish between kernel and user threads, except that kernel code running in critical sections cannot be preempted.  An I/O task is precisely when preemption occurs, since the code should sleep until I/O completes.  I/O-bound code should use very little CPU.

Thank you for your answer, it's useful. But I wonder if there is no IO in kernel thread, just time-consuming work, will it be preempted?

It is running in kernel mode, so it will only get preempted when it goes to sleep, gets interrupted, or reschedules itself voluntarily, same as a user thread running in kernel mode (during a system call), but maybe running at a higher priority.
